# Is it possible to find a deleted xcode file?

Tags: xcode, macos, delete-file

I highlighted a line of code I was going to delete after building and running the app. After I ran the app, the code was still highlighted so I pressed delete and my entire class was deleted... I am an idiot...

The file did not go to the trash so I thought xcode might store it somewhere, does anyone know if it is possible to retrieve this file?

Comment: when you press the backspace key xcodes asks if you want to remove reference or move to trash... if you just pressed enter after the backspace your file will still be in your file system and you can just add it to the project again...

Comment: @Felipe Sabino I pressed enter but I can't find the file

Comment: then it is not deleted... can't you find it anywhere using finder or spotlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily revert if you are using version control. if you are not using it (yet), you should -- worse things happen.

if you don't use version control and you use xcode's snapshots... you could look there. you may also be able to find it using Time Machine.

but... add "learn version control" to your #1 thing to learn this week for development.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was my main class too. Oh well, i remember most of it

Answer (score 0):

I used the Disk Drill to restore mistakenly deleted files.

check http://www.cleverfiles.com/